# Passing id of tag that submited form with onchange=this.form.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to know which select tag submitted form?

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <select id="id1" name="sel1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Second</option>
    </select>

    <select id="id2" name="sel2" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Second</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Non-jQuery solution is preferable, but not mandatory...

P.S. Problem is that `selected="select"` attribute is generated dynamically (i don't know which option would be selected as default - so i can't compare default with submitted)

Comment: select->(via js function)hidden text box->php(using GET or POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is a hidden field with a value you set. Something like this should do.

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitselect" value="" id="submitselect">
    <select id="id1" name="sel1" onchange="document.getElementById('submitselect').value='sel1';this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Second</option>
    </select>

    <select id="id2" name="sel2" onchange="document.getElementById('submitselect').value='sel2';this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Second</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could have a default option chosen, e.g.

```
<option value="" selected>-</option>
```

That would never otherwise be chosen. That way, this option would remain unset in the `select`s that didn't cause the submit.

Comment: so, form will be submitted on any selection change using this code? (about default chosen option - i don't have permissions to set default option)

Comment: Yes, the form will be submitted on any selection change, just like your current code. What do you mean you don't have permission to set default option? You're already setting one using `selected="selected"`.

Comment: That was an example... I don't know which will be selected.. I also don't know how many `<options>` fields per `<select>` would be, or even how many `<select>` elements will be generated... Easiest way is to pass 'id' of <select> which triggered form submission.... By the way, thanks for the answer :)